# Coordinate or world line? Understanding a simple example problem

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, action, variational-calculus

I'm trying to follow a simple example from Misner's *Gravitation* (p. 181). Misner takes the action integral

$$I = \frac{1}{2}m\int\left(\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}\right)\dot{z}^\mu\dot{z}^\nu\,d\tau,$$

where $z = z(\tau)$ is a parameterized world line for a test particle. He finds that $\delta I = 0$ when

$$\frac{d}{d\tau}\left[\left(\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}\right)\dot{z}^\nu\right] - \frac{1}{2}h_{\alpha\beta,\mu}\dot{z}^\alpha\dot{z}^\beta = 0.$$

My answer, however, according the Euler-Lagrange equations, is rather that

$$\frac{d}{d\tau}\left[\left(\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}\right)\dot{z}^\nu\right] - \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial h_{\alpha\beta}}{\partial z^\mu}\dot{z}^\alpha\dot{z}^\beta = 0.$$

But I would have thought that $$\frac{\partial h_{\alpha\beta}}{\partial x^\mu} = h_{\alpha\beta,\mu}\quad\mathrm{and\,not\,that}\qquad\frac{\partial h_{\alpha\beta}}{\partial z^\mu} = h_{\alpha\beta,\mu}.$$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You already solved the problem: your notation is more rigorous and explains what he means with $h_{\alpha \beta,\mu}$

Comment: You need mention that $h_{\alpha\beta}(z(\tau))$.

Comment: @Mathphysmeister please consider posting this an an answer.